InfluxDB line protocol export without data
I try to export my data from an InfluxDB bucket with the following command:
influxd inspect export-lp --bucket-id 92099289ecc05da7 --engine-path /var/lib/influxdb/engine --output-path ~/backup/influxdb20240430bucket05da7export.lp

I am following steps from docs:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/reference/cli/influxd/inspect/export-lp/
The file size of the exported .lp file is always 0 bytes with above command or 23 bytes if I extend above command and restrict measurements time rage.
Printout to console is:
{"level":"info","ts":1714462130.370241,"caller":"export_lp/export_lp.go:219","msg":"exporting TSM files","tsm_dir":"/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/92099289ecc05da7","file_count":0}
{"level":"info","ts":1714462130.3703382,"caller":"export_lp/export_lp.go:315","msg":"exporting WAL files","wal_dir":"/var/lib/influxdb/engine/wal/92099289ecc05da7","file_count":0}
{"level":"info","ts":1714462130.3703575,"caller":"export_lp/export_lp.go:204","msg":"export complete"}

InfluxDB contains bucket with 92099289ecc05da7, db backup is more than 50MB, measurements are mostly in this bucket.
Engine I verify with http://localhost:8086/api/v2/config:
engine-path "/var/lib/influxdb/engine"
Bucket ID I verify with either UI Load Data -> Buckets or command influx bucket list.
OSS, InfluxDB v2.7.4, Server: 19e5c0e, Frontend: 9d25a2f.
(My use case is to duplicate data from OSS do cloud but I do not see a feature to force already existing data to be synchronized while using replication, seems while doing replication only writes can be copied so the proper mechanism is to use export-lp as above.)
Base of console printout I do not know why export contains not data. What I am doing wrong?

I had a similar issue. In my case, the issue was coming from the wrong engine path. To find the path, just check the configuration file in /etc/influxdb/config.toml.
The content of my config.toml file:
....
engine-path = "/mnt/data/influxdb/engine" # Path to the engine
...


Therefore, I had to provide it as value to the  engine argument.

Your answer would be improved if you added details such as which configuration key was causing your issue.
